# Подогнать по высоте Item в RecyclerView

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как автоматически подгонять по высоте recyclerview_item, чтобы он был равен ширине колонки, в общем делать квадратным ?
Сейчас ~ 180 dp установлено в макете..

```
recyclerview_item.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="180dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/obvodka"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Колонки подгоняются под ширину экрана при повороте:

```
 //отследить поворот экрана
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if(recyclerView.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    } else if (recyclerView.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
    }

}
```

Адаптер:

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Context contextActivity;


private String[] mData = new String[0];
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

// Data is passed into the constructor
public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, String[] data) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mData = data;
    contextActivity = context;
}

// Inflates the cell layout from xml when needed
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

// Binds the data to the textview in each cell
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String animal = mData[position];
    holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
}

// Total number of cells
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.length;
}

// Stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView myTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

// Convenience method for getting data at click position
public String getItem(int id) {
    return mData[id];
}

// Method that executes your code for the action received
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
   Toast.makeText(contextActivity, String.valueOf(position + 1),     0).show();
}
}
```

Добавил так:

```
// Stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView myTextView;
    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        if (itemView.getWidth() > 0) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(itemView.getWidth(),itemView.getWidth());
            itemView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        } else {
            ViewTreeObserver vto = itemView.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                     itemView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(itemView.getWidth(),itemView.getWidth());
                    itemView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}


Исправил макет:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/obvodka"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Все равно ошибка !

Comment: можно попробовать fill_parent например

Comment: не, тогда во всю высоту экрана Item, надо как-то рассчитывать..

Comment: wrap_content я так понимаю тоже не подходит?

Comment: Не понимаю как задать высоту, равную ширине.. В адаптере типа того: @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
        view.setMinimumHeight(view.getWidth());
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать в адаптере вот так (программно изменять высоту вью после отрисовки):

```
if (view.getWidth() > 0) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(view.getWidth(),view.getWidth());
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    } else {
        ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(view.getWidth(),view.getWidth());
                view.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        });
}
```

А сам LinearLayout задать как `wrap_content`

Comment: Немножко вылетает с ошибкой.. Если убрать вторую часть условия, то не вылетает, но и не отрисовывает квадраты.. Не успевает правильно получить view.getWidth(), оно 0 равно.

Comment: вылетает потому, что вы применяете ко всему view (у которого нет родителя == LinearLayout). Добавьте в основной LL (который должен быть wrap_content по высоте) вью, с которым будете работать

Comment: Добавил код адаптера в вопрос.. Не пойму куда добавить, у меня  view.getWidth() = 0..

Comment: Добавьте во вьюхолдер и view замените на ваш itemView

Comment: Я в вопросе написал, как исправил, все равно не получается.. Та же ошибка, и view.getWidth() = 0

Comment: ну ошибку тогда покажите из стэктрейса. Или посмотрите в какой строчке она (выделено синей "ссылкой") и как называется

Comment: Вот так работает ваш код, без ваших внутренностей в условиях.. Иначе ошибка и я не понял как обернуть макет.. ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    view.setMinimumHeight(view.getWidth());
                }
            });

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой layout. Код не нужен.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/obvodka"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

ЗЫ для androidx будет `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`